# Dijkstra's shortest path

Tags: python

I'm VERY new to Python (self learning) and am writing some code, and have read as much as possible (both on this website and youtube) to figure it out, and I'm perplexed as to why it's not working for me

I've generated this dictionary of dictionaries (may not be most efficient, please let me know how to improve, been doing this a couple weeks only):

```
graphx = []
all_locs = []
def graph(width, height):
    for r in range(height):
        row = []
        for c in range(width):
            t = (r, c)
            row.append(t)
            all_locs.append(t)
        graphx.append(row)
graph(width, height)

# # Builds a dictionary of all nodes, and their weight
weighted_grid = {}
for node in graphx:
    for c in node:
        n = {}
        s = {}
        e = {}
        w = {}
        if (c[0] < height) and (c[0] > 0):
            n[c[0] + 1, c[1]] = 1
            s[c[0] - 1, c[1]] = 1
        elif c[0] == 0:
            n[c[0] + 1, c[1]] = 1
        elif c[0] == height:
            s[c[0] - 1, c[1]] = 1
        if c[1] < width and c[1] > 0:
            e[c[0], c[1] + 1] = 1
            w[c[0], c[1] - 1] = 1
        elif c[1] == 0:
            e[c[0], c[1] + 1] = 1
        elif c[1] == height:
            w[c[0], c[1] - 1] = 1
        temp = {}
        blank = {}
        if n != blank:
            temp[c[0] + 1, c[1]] = 1
        if e != blank:
            temp[c[0], c[1] + 1] = 1
        if s != blank:
            temp[c[0] - 1, c[1]] = 1
        if w != blank:
            temp[c[0], c[1] - 1] = 1
        weighted_grid[c[0],c[1]] = temp
```

When I run dijikstras, using the the tuples as start and destination, I get an error.   Here's the version of dijkstras I'm running:

```
def dijkstra(graph, start, goal):
shortest_distance = {}  # records the current cost to reach that node.
track_predecessor = {}  # keeps track of the path that led to this node.
unseen_nodes = graph    # Iterate through the graph to check all nodes.
infinity = 99999        # Make it any large number,greater than possible path weights.
track_path = []               # gives us the trace-back path of the optimal route

for node in unseen_nodes:
    shortest_distance[node] = infinity
shortest_distance[start] = 0

while unseen_nodes:

    min_distance_node = None
    for node in unseen_nodes:
        if min_distance_node is None:
            min_distance_node = node
        elif shortest_distance[node] < shortest_distance[min_distance_node]:
            min_distance_node = node

    path_options = graph[min_distance_node].items()

    for child_node, weight in path_options:

        if weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node] < shortest_distance[child_node]:
            shortest_distance[child_node] = weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node]
            track_predecessor[child_node] = min_distance_node

    unseen_nodes.pop(min_distance_node)

current_node = goal
while current_node != start:
    try:
        track_path.insert(0, current_node)
        current_node = track_predecessor[current_node]
    except KeyError:
        break
track_path.insert(0, start)

if shortest_distance[goal] != infinity:
    pass
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/Important/PycharmProjects/DMT2/dungeonmasterstome/Main.py", line 318, in <module>
    dijkstra(weighted_grid, (0, 0), (0,1))
  File "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/Important/PycharmProjects/DMT2/dungeonmasterstome/Main.py", line 300, in dijkstra
    if weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node] < shortest_distance[child_node]:
KeyError: (0, 30)
```

Thoughts and thanks for any help and constructive criticism.

Comment: I've just done a quick google search and found this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/. Check it out.

Comment: Also, just search `Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm` and you will find countless examples.

Comment: I've looked at both of those, and for whatever reason, the error keeps saying certain points don't work, even if the nodes are next to each other. :\

Comment: Huh weird. Well, wait a bit while I see the problem.